# How to set direction of spin tool blender

Tags: bezier-curves

I want to create a pipe with multiple curves see image below:
[image]
I have done this with the spin tool but now i want my curve to follow the blue arrow instead of what it does now.. How do i do this i cant find any menu to change this :( or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply invert the rotation to -90d in the Transform pane ('T' by default)

[image: Image of pipe rotate as required by the question in Blender]

Comment: you should note that you will have to flip the normals when doing this.

Comment: Awesome could you maybe elaborate on how to get to this menu where u can rotate it -90 degrees? i cant seem to find it anywhere :(

Comment: Press T, it's the transform pane.